# Is this a bug in z3 int.to.str?

Tags: z3, smt

I'm posting [this z3 issue](https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/issues/1500) here too in case any z3 users have somehow encountered it. We are experimenting a little with the semantics of **int.to.str**, and we found this **weird behavior** that **looks like a bug**. Here is the first query that works OK:

```
(declare-const s String)
(declare-const i    Int)

(assert (< i -2))

(assert (= s (int.to.str i)))
(assert (< 0 (str.len s   )))

(check-sat)
(get-value (s i))
```

And the result:

```
sat
((s "-11")
 (i (- 11)))
```

When I change the '<' sign to '=' I get an unsat response:

```
(declare-const s String)
(declare-const i    Int)

(assert (= i -2))

(assert (= s (int.to.str i)))
(assert (< 0 (str.len s   )))

(check-sat)
(get-value (s i))
```

Here is the result I get:

```
unsat
(error "line 10 column 16: model is not available")
```

Am I missing something here? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is indeed a bug, as described [here](https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/issues/1500).